# How to customize facebook and google login buttons

Tags: android, button, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm trying to build an application that users can sign up with Google or Facebook account
I also want to make my app clean and simple, so i don't want the default login buttons.
I stumbled upon 9gag login page and i like what they did.
can anyone please tell me how to make buttons like they did?

[image]

this is my code:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnFaceBookLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/facebook_blue">


      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"

         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/write_title"
         android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_inverse_icon" />


     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_height="35dp"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"

         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebook_icon"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook_icon"
         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
         android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
     </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: simply create buttons and set there background to some image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ans"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Google"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/facebook"
        android:src="@drawable/ans" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Google"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Sign In" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Forget Pass" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have use image with dimensions 480*60. Its work fine.